# object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded when running chromium

Tags: permissions, security, chromium, ld, gtk3-nocsd

## Problem description

When I run `chromium` in a bash shell, I get this message: `ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.` However, when I run a regular executable, such as a `helloworld` program compiled by gcc, the error message isn't generated.

## Platform

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | linux |
| architecture | aarch64 |
| release | Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS |

## My research

I use `ldd` to locate `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` and it turns out that both `helloworld` and `chromium` can correctly find the absolute path of that shared object.

```bash
$ ldd helloworld | grep -F libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x0000ffffa9a73000)

$ ldd /snap/bin/chromium | grep -F libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x0000ffff7e370000)

$ ldd /snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome | grep -F libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x0000ffff7a299000)
```

Some information about the `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` shared object are listed below. Pay attention that there's a `setuid` bit in its access rights.

```bash
$ ls -l /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 
-rwSr--r-- 1 root root 26464 Mar  3  2018 /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

The `$LD_PRELOAD` environment variable is set here:

```bash
$ sudo grep -2r LD_PRELOAD /etc/
...
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect-          if [ x"$GTK_CSD"x = x"0"x ] ; then
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect:              export LD_PRELOAD="libgtk3-nocsd.so.0${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect-          fi
...
```

The following document might account for this problem?

```bash
$ sudo grep -2r LD_PRELOAD /etc/
...
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers-  # While the chromium and chrome sandboxes are setuid root, they only link
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers-  # in limited libraries so glibc's secure execution should be enough to not
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers:  # require the santized_helper (ie, LD_PRELOAD will only use standard system
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-helpers-  # paths (man ld.so)).
...

$ man ld.so
...
              In  secure-execution  mode, preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored.  Furthermore, shared objects are preloaded only from the stan‐
              dard search directories and only if they have set-user-ID mode bit enabled (which is not typical).
...
```

## My solutions

According to the document above, I've worked out two solutions.

- set `$LD_PRELOAD` to the absolute path of `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`
  The document suggests that `LD_PRELOAD will only use standard system paths` in the case of `the chromium and chrome sandboxes`. Therefore, one might replace `export LD_PRELOAD="libgtk3-nocsd.so.0${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"` with `export LD_PRELOAD="/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect` and then restart the desktop environment. Pay attention that the absolute path of `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` varies on different platforms.
- run `chromium` as root without using sandboxes
  The problem seems to be related to the use of `the chromium and chrome sandboxes` which are `setuid root`, as is indicated in the document. Running `chromium` as root without using sandboxes (e.g. `sudo chromium --no-sandbox`) seems to suppress the error message. Unfortunately, this behaviour might bring about a warning from the browser (`You are using an unsupported command-line flag:--no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer.`).

## My questions

- What does the so-called `standard system paths`/`standard search directories` in the document mean? There is a record of `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` in `/etc/ld.so.cache`, and `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` is included in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/aarch64-linux-gnu.conf`. Isn't `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` a `standard system path`/`standard search directory`?

  ```bash
  $ grep -aoP '(?<=\x00)[^\x00]*?libgtk3-nocsd\.so\.0' /etc/ld.so.cache
  libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
  /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0

  $ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/aarch64-linux-gnu.conf
  # Multiarch support
  /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  ```
- As is illustrated in the document, `in  secure-execution  mode, preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored`. Does that mean `$LD_PRELOAD` will be ignored if it's an absolute path like `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`?
- Which solution is safer and more reasonable? Are there any better solutions? Is there anything else that I misunderstood?

Comment: You're behind on applying security fixes if your provided details are correct. I'd check your system.. Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ for the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded to 20.04.6 before this date.